# The two circles are externally tangent.If the radius of bigger and smaller circles are 6 and 2 respectively.Then the area of quadrilateral $PQSR$ is

Tags: geometry, circles

The two circles are externally tangent as shown in the figure.If the radius of bigger and smaller circles are 6 and 2 respectively.Then the area of quadrilateral $PQSR$ is

$(A)24\sqrt3\hspace{1 cm}(B)12\sqrt3\hspace{1 cm}(C)12\hspace{1 cm}(D)24$

I tried and thought hard but no known formula or method seems to come at aid.Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Hope you can continue with that.

---

**This is the final version with minor mistakes corrected:-**

[image]

Comment: Sir i have corrected the typo,i have written the question in cyclic fashion,This method does not seem to help in area of quadrilateral $PQRS$.Please guide me.Thanks,@Mick

Comment: @Brahmagupta Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be the centers of the smaller and the bigger circle respectively. First of all, $PQSR$ is NOT a quadrilateral (because a quadrilateral has only 4 sides). Actually, the area of the figure, $PQSR = PQC_2C_1 + C_1C_2SR = 2 \times PQC_2C_1$

Comment: Sir i have edited the figure to make it elaborate.I mean quadrilateral PQSR,is there a way to find the area of this figure.Thanks in advance.@Mick

Comment: @Brahmagupta I am sorry for mis-reading your question. Here is how:- (1) Find $\angle QC_2S = … = 60^0$. (2) Do you know $\angle PC_1R = \angle QC_2S$. (3) Find $[ \triangle QC_2S]$ by area formula $(0.5 ab \sin C) …. = h, say. (4) Find $[ \triangle PC_1R] = … = k$, say. (5) Required area $= 2 \times PQC_2C_1 + k – h$.

Comment: @Brahmagupta (4) Find $[ \triangle PC_1R] = k$, say. (5) Required area $= 2 \times PQC_2C_1 + k – h$.

Comment: Sir angle $QC_2S$ cannot be 60 degree because side $QS$ is not 6,6 is the radius of bigger circle.Sorry for bothering you again and again@Mick

Answer (score 0):

First, you can prove that PQRS is a trapezoid and use the corresponding formula. Then notice that the two circles with their corresponding details are similar. Using this and a bit of trigonometry, you can find the angle between the two tangent lines. At the end, the answer is A (If I have not made any mistakes).